# Creating SSL certificate for online IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, iis-7

I have configured a home computer to run a public IIS server and am having issues with creating an SSL certificate which I can use to allow my hosted ASP .NET application on a Facebook canvas. Is there anyone who has done something similar here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm almost certain you need a "real" SSL Certificate, bought and issued from a Certified Authority. Self signed certificates will not work because they will not be trusted.

Comment: +1. Yes, it costs. Yes, it is nagging. No, it still is needed.